# Trying to set data-mfp-src attribute for magnific-popup using jquery

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I'm modifying a Wordpress theme that utilizes magnific popup.

I'd like to replace the URL from the anchor tags with empty strings, and populate the data-mfp-src attribute with the URL instead. This is to prevent middle clicking to open the source image in a new tab and to hide the URL from the status bar (I'm aware it'll still be visible in the page source).

I've tried this:

```
$('.photowall-item a').each(function(idx,link) {
    $(this).attr('data-mfp-src', link);
    $(this).attr('href', '');
});
```

I've also tried setting data-mfp-src using `$(this).attr('href')` instead of link.

The result in either case when the page is loaded is that href is replaced with the empty string, data-mfp-src is created but also contains an empty string instead of the original href value. If I assign a different value to href, data-mfp-src gets the same value. This breaks the popup.

If I assign a hardcoded value to data-mfp-src eg. `$(this).attr('data-mfp-src', 'someurl')` it works dandy, but obviously the same image will pop up no matter which thumbnail you click.

Also strange, if I do an `alert($(this).attr('data-mfp-src'))` right after blanking href, the correct value for data-mfp-src is returned. But when I view the generated source in my browser, the value is gone.

Comment: where and how do you set up idx and link?

Comment: If you want to prevent middle clicking to open the source image in a new tab you just have to return false: $(this).on('click', function(){return false;}); or $(this).on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});

Comment: idx contains the index of the current anchor element, link contains the href. These get passed in automatically.

Comment: I initially thought about trying to disable middle-clicking, but at least in Firefox it doesn't work (works in Chrome). I read somewhere that it isn't possible and gave up. The above examples don't work in FF.

Comment: You might want to add more code to see what is interfering. write the whole code.

Comment: Yeah, there wouldn't have been a way to diagnose this without seeing the whole code. I was hesitant to post it because it's from a paid theme. I assumed my lack of jquery knowledge was at fault with it was really an issue with the code flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that this code is inserted into gets called twice *slaps forehead*

data-mfp-src and href get set correctly the first time. The second time, the empty string that was assigned to href then overwrites the correct URL that was assigned in data-mfp-src.

I fixed it by defining an array, then testing whether it's empty. If it's empty, I populate the array with hrefs and move on. If it's not empty, I assign the previously assigned hrefs to data-mfp-src and blank out the hrefs.

Works like a charm.